# Choosing eclipse version for installing Flash Builder 4 plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, flashbuilder4

I need to choose a version of eclipse to install the Flash Builder 4 plugin on.
What versions of eclipse are most suitable for the plugin?
Are there any known problems with the latest version? (currently 3.6.1 I believe)
Are there any officially supported versions? / unsupported versions?

Answer (score 1):

I use the latest Eclipse release (Helios 3.6.1) with the Flash Builder 4 plugin.  I find Flash Builder 4 to be a little flaky in general, but nothing to stop me delivering my software.

I develop Flex on top of Java, which is why I want the latest version of Eclipse.  I develop both Flex and Java in the same Eclipse workspace.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the stand alone, which has eclipse in it.
I use this one and I just install all my plugins in the stand alone.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but my question is specific on the subject of choosing eclipse version to go with the FB 4 plugin.

Answer (score 0):

From the installation manual:

> Install Flash Builder 4 Plug-in on
>   Windows: NOTE: **Flash Builder 4 is
>   only supported on Eclipse 3.4 or
>   3.5**. CAUTION: Do not install the plug-in version of Flash Builder 4
>   into a copy of Eclipse that is already
>   hosting Flex Builder 3 plug-in. If you
>   want to continue running Flex Builder
>   3 plug-in, download a new copy of
>   Eclipse and use that when installing
>   Flash Builder 4 plug-in, or choose
>   bundled Eclipse option in the
>   installer. In addition, be sure to use
>   separate Eclipse workspaces for each
>   installation.